# What's the right type for GCP cloud run in a deployment manager?

Tags: google-cloud-run, google-deployment-manager

Attempting to use a deployment manager to create a Cloud Run, as follows:

```
resources:
- name: myService_cloudRun
  type: gcp-types/run-v1:projects.locations.services
  properties:
    location: us-east1
    serviceId: myService
    template:
      metadata:
        name: dekart
        annotations:
          run.googleapis.com/ingress: all
      spec:
        containers:
        - image: x/y:z
```

Which gives me

```
message: The provider run-v1 at project gcp-types was not found in public GCP types
```

And indeed, this is not in [this list of types](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/supported-resource-types) -- but I don't see anything resembling cloud run. Thoughts?

Comment: `While Deployment Manager will remain running and supported for as long as customers need, we do not recommend customers take any new dependencies on DM.` Source: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193281069#comment3 My recommendation is to migrate to Terraform which has extensive support within Google and the community.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deploying Cloud Run using Deployment Manager is [unsupported and infeasible](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/193281069) as of the moment and [Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_run_service) would be best to implement this instead.

You may, however, check this [old post](https://gist.github.com/dinvlad/fcf72039c403bc2bf46663fb43c62a57) where you can find an example on how to implement it and its [workaround](https://gist.github.com/dinvlad/fcf72039c403bc2bf46663fb43c62a57#gistcomment-3030701)